# Remove Query String from the end of the URL after passing through Rewrite Map

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, rewritemap

I have a list of several hundred URL redirects/rewrites inside of a rewrite map. Most of the URL's contain query strings that match a specific entry in the rewrite map. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510132/how-to-redirect-source-url-with-query-string-by-using-redirectmap-in-apache) on how to pass the query string into the rewrite map. I got this working fine but the problem now is that the existing query string is appended to the end of the rewritten URL. For example:

```
Expected Rewrite:
/subdir/dir.cfm?categoryID=123 -> https://example.com/subdir/endurl   

Actual Rewrite:
https://example.com/subdir/endurl?categoryID=123

Expected Rewrite
/subdir/dir.cfm?videoID=3422424-131FDDFD-234 -> https://example.com/subdir/awesome/stuff

Actual Rewrite:
https://example.com/subdir/awesome/stuff?videoID=3422424-131FDDFD-234
```

This is the rewrite rules I have:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap redirects dbm=sdbm:C:\Apache24\conf\redirects.sdbm
RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(cfm|cfml)) ${redirects:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} [NC,R=301,L]
```

How can I remove the query string appended to the URL after the rewrite?

EDIT

I was able to actually get this working using this:

```
RewriteMap redirects dbm=sdbm:C:\Apache24\conf\redirects.sdbm
RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(cfm|cfml)) ${redirects:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} [NC,C]
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [L,R=301]
```

However I am not sure if someone knows of a better way to accomplish what I am doing? I am thinking this might break if I ever have to redirect to a URL that contains a query string to another url that contains a query string.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache version 2.4.0 and later, you can use [[QSD]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag (Query String Discard):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(cfm|cfml)) ${redirects:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} [QSD,NC]
```

In Apache version 2.2, there is no [QSD] flag, but if the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is to discard the existing query string, so by just adding a `?` to your rewrite URI, you will get the same effect:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(cfm|cfml)) ${redirects:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}}? [NC]
```

(your newly added rewrite rule actually uses this feature)